# Corrección a barril de petróleo

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Me enviaron esta tarea, hice esto, pero me dijeron que lo hice mal, ¿Me ayudan a corregir por favor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ha realizado un muestreo con los precios del barril de petróleo durante el último mes (de 30 días), suponga que dichos valores son enteros y que han fluctuado entre P y Q dólares $ (en forma aleatoria).

Una vez elaborada la muestra, se desea determinar:

El promedio del precio del petróleo

¿Cuál fue el día en el que estuvo más barato el barril de petróleo?

¿Cuántos días el petróleo tuvo precios superiores al promedio?

```
  #include <iostream>
  #define DIAS 30
  using namespace std;
  void barril(int vec[], int);
  void muestra(int vec[], int);
  int promedio(int suma,int vec[], int);
  int el_mas_barato(int menor, int vec[], int);
  void superior(int prom, int vec[], int);
  int main()
  {
      int i, suma = 0, menor = 0;
      int vector[100];
      barril(vector,DIAS);
      muestra(vector, DIAS);
      promedio(suma,vector,DIAS);
      el_mas_barato(menor, vector, DIAS);
      superior(suma,vector,DIAS);
      return 0;
  }
  void barril(int vec[], int tam){
      for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
          cout<<"Precios: "<<endl;
          cin>>vec[i];
      }
  }
  void muestra(int vec[], int tam){
      for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
          cout<<"El precio del vector es: "<< vec[i]<<endl;
      }
  }
  int promedio(int suma,int vec[], int tam){
      suma = 0;
      int promedio = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
          suma = suma + vec[i];
      }
      promedio = suma / DIAS;
      cout<<"Promedio Total: "<<promedio<<endl;;
      return promedio;
  }

  int el_mas_barato(int menor, int vec[], int tam){
      menor=vec[0];
      int pos = 0, i;
      for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
          if(vec[i] < menor)
              menor = vec[i];
      }       pos = i; 
      cout<<"El dia que el barril estuvo mas barato: "<<pos<<"Con el precio de: "<<menor<<endl;
      return menor;
  }

  void superior(int prom, int vec[], int tam){
      int i, pos= 0;
      for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
          if(vec[i] > prom){
              pos = i;
              cout<<"los dias que fueron superior al promedio: "<<pos<<endl;       
          }else{
              cout<<"Estan debajo del promedio"<<endl;
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código?

Comment: Me dijeron que no lo hice de manera aleatoria, al valor del barril del petróleo por día, y no se como hacerlo aleatorio ):
Y siempre se repite el resultado de la misma manera

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


#define MAXIMO 100
using namespace std;
void barril(int vec[]);
int promedio(int suma,int vec[]);
int el_mas_barato(int menor, int vec[]);
void superior(int mayor, int vec[]);
const int elementos = 31;
int main()
{
    cout<<"\n *****Precio Barril Petroleo****"<<endl<<endl;
    system ("pause");
    int i, suma = 0, menor = 0;
    int vector[30];
    barril(vector);
    suma = promedio(suma,vector);
    cout<<"El promedio total: "<<suma<<endl<<endl;
    el_mas_barato(menor, vector);
    superior(suma,vector);
    return 0;
}
void barril(int vec[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<elementos;i++){
        vec[i] = rand() % MAXIMO;
    }
    for(i=0;i<elementos;i++){
        cout <<"Dia [" << i << "] = Precio del Barril $"<< vec[ i ];cout<<endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int promedio(int suma,int vec[]){
    suma = 0;
    float promedio = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<elementos;i++){
        suma += vec[i];
        promedio = suma/elementos;
    }
    return promedio;
}


int el_mas_barato(int menor, int vec[]){
    menor=vec[0];
    int pos = 1, i;
    for(i=0;i<elementos;i++){
        if(vec[i] < menor){
            menor = vec[i];
            pos = i;
        }
    }        
    cout<<"el Dia: "<<pos<<" obtuvo el precio mas barato del barril con: $"<<menor<<endl<<endl;
    return menor;
    
}

void superior(int mayor, int vec[]){
    int i,suma;
    int promedio1 = promedio(suma,vec);
    for(i=0;i<elementos;i++){
        if(vec[i] > promedio1){
            cout<<"los dias que fueron superior al promedio: "<<vec[i]<<endl<<endl;
            
        }
    }
}
```